# VisualStateGroups not found?

Tags: c#, silverlight, visualstategroup

I have a XAML of a ui control (which inherits from a button) and have various visual state groups in it as follows:

```
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="Green" Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.94" Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.94" Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard/>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>

                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="MyState">
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed_Green">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="Yellow" Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.94" Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.94" Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>




                        </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

In codebehind in the onapplytemplte function I try:

```
VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(this).Count
```

But the return value is '0', shouldn't it be 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager.visualstategroups.aspx) is set on the root element in the control template of your control (i.e. `this`), not on the control itself. You would need to give your root element an `x:Name` and then access it using [GetTemplateChild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.gettemplatechild%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).